# Processing Fix & Optimization of https://github.com/jonlit/spacestarprocessing3d

Tags: processing

I previously had an issue with a model not loading correctly (see [Processing - loading obj File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72909272/processing-loading-obj-file/))
https://stackoverflow.com/users/89766/george-profenza helped me solve the problem in chat, and he wanted to post his optimizations to my code publically.
This also solved the original problem described in the question mentioned above.

You can check out the game at https://github.com/jonlit/spacestarprocessing3d

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in chat there were a few things slightly off with the existing approach and for visiblity, this are the steps taken to address the issues.

Hope this helps other to debug Processing P3D / OBJ issues:

**The first step** was to identify the slowest pieces of code. This was done using [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/).

This highlighted `shape()` calls were slow (not not why):

[image: visual vm 1]

[image: visual vm 2]

**Step 2** was to isolate the problem. Why is loading/displaying a couple of obj files slow.

For reference these are the assets:

- [rock.obj](https://github.com/JonLit/SpaceStarProcessing3D/blob/main/data/rock.obj) using [rockTexture.png](https://github.com/JonLit/SpaceStarProcessing3D/blob/main/data/rockTexture.png) (but currently missing .mtl)
- [cirno_low.obj](https://github.com/JonLit/SpaceStarProcessing3D/blob/main/data/cirno_low.obj) using [cirno_low_u1_v1.jpeg](https://github.com/JonLit/SpaceStarProcessing3D/blob/main/data/cirno_low_u1_v1.jpeg)

This is a test sketch loading/display the .obj files as they are:

```java
PShape rock;
PShape cirno;

void setup(){
  size(900, 900, P3D);
  cirno = loadShape("cirno_low.obj");
  rock = loadShape("rock.obj");
  
  int faces = 0;
  int vertices = 0;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < rock.getChildCount(); i++){
    PShape c = rock.getChild(i);
    vertices += c.getVertexCount();
    faces++;
  }
  println("rock faces", faces, "vertices", vertices);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  lights();
  translate(width * 0.5, height * 0.5, 0);
  rotateY(map(mouseX, 0, width, -PI, PI));
  rotateX(map(mouseY, 0, height, PI, -PI));
  
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 81; i++){
    pushMatrix();
    translate(i % 9 * 100 - width * 0.5, 
              i / 9 * 100 - height * 0.5, -100);
    rotate(map(i, 0, 80, -PI, PI), 0.5, 0.5, 0);
    scale(0.5);
    shape(rock);
    popMatrix();
  }
  
  pushMatrix();
    scale(10);
    shape(cirno);
  popMatrix();
  
  surface.setTitle((int)frameRate + "fps");
}
```

It renders pretty fast, without textures though:
[image: multiple rock objs in a square grid with an anime doll model on top]

[The game](https://github.com/JonLit/SpaceStarProcessing3D/blob/main/Flugobjekt.pde#L24) uses [`setTexture()`](https://processing.org/tutorials/pshape/#3d-and-textureshttps://processing.org/tutorials/pshape/#3d-and-textures) and interestingly enough this drops the frame rate:

```java
PShape rock;
PShape cirno;

void setup(){
  size(900, 900, P3D);
  cirno = loadShape("cirno_low.obj");
  cirno.setTexture(loadImage("cirno_low_u1_v1.jpeg"));
  
  rock = loadShape("rock.obj");
  rock.setTexture(loadImage("rockTexture.png"));
  
  int faces = 0;
  int vertices = 0;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < rock.getChildCount(); i++){
    PShape c = rock.getChild(i);
    vertices += c.getVertexCount();
    faces++;
  }
  println("rock faces", faces, "vertices", vertices);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  lights();
  translate(width * 0.5, height * 0.5, 0);
  rotateY(map(mouseX, 0, width, -PI, PI));
  rotateX(map(mouseY, 0, height, PI, -PI));
  
  for(int i = 0 ; i < 81; i++){
    pushMatrix();
    translate(i % 9 * 100 - width * 0.5, 
              i / 9 * 100 - height * 0.5, -100);
    rotate(map(i, 0, 80, -PI, PI), 0.5, 0.5, 0);
    scale(0.5);
    shape(rock);
    popMatrix();
  }
  
  pushMatrix();
    scale(10);
    shape(cirno);
  popMatrix();
  
  surface.setTitle((int)frameRate + "fps");
}
```

[image: same models with textures but low frame rate]

Without checking the PShape source code, the assumption is behind the scenes the PShape has to do more work behind the scenes, because loading an .obj file with an .mtl (which helps load the texture as well) render just fine.

Here's the **Processing > Examples > Basics > Shape > LoadDisplayOBJ** example tweaked: it renders 1250 instances at 60fps:

```java
/**
 * Load and Display an OBJ Shape. 
 * 
 * The loadShape() command is used to read simple SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics)
 * files and OBJ (Object) files into a Processing sketch. This example loads an
 * OBJ file of a rocket and displays it to the screen. 
 */


PShape rocket;

float ry;
  
public void setup() {
  size(900, 900, P3D);
    
  rocket = loadShape("rocket.obj");
}

public void draw() {
  background(0);
  lights();
  
  translate(width/2, height/2 + 100, -200);
  rotateY(map(mouseX, 0, width, -PI, PI));
  rotateX(map(mouseY, 0, height, PI, -PI));
  
  int nc = 1250;
  float nr = sqrt(nc);
  float sp = 150;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < nc; i++){
    pushMatrix();
    translate(i % nr * sp - width * 0.5, 
              i / nr * sp - height * 0.5, -sp);
    //rotate(map(i, 0, 80, -PI, PI), 0.5, 0.5, 0);
    rotateZ(PI + radians(i));
    rotateY(ry);
    scale(0.5);
    shape(rocket);
    popMatrix();
  }

  
  //rotateZ(PI);
  //rotateY(ry);
  //shape(rocket);
  
  ry += 0.02;
  
  surface.setTitle((int)frameRate + "fps");
}
```

[image: 1250 rocket.obj models in a grid at 60fps]

This pointed out another issue with how the obj files were used in the game:
each [`new Star()`](https://github.com/JonLit/SpaceStarProcessing3D/blob/main/Flugobjekt.pde#L23) for example would load the .obj again.

```java
public class Star extends UFO {
    public Star (int x, int y, int spd) {
        posX = x;
        posY = y;
        rot = int(random(0, 360));
        speed = spd;  
    symbol = loadShape("rock.obj");
    symbol.setTexture(rockTexture); //<>//
    ...
```

Ideally these meshes would be loaded once in setup(), with .mtl files and references passed to each instance needing to render them via `shape()`.
This would allow [instancing](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Instancing) to work as it's the same geometry rendered multiple times. Reloading the same obj file into new memory addresses for each instance would result in many duplicated resources.

One quick fix for the .mtl issue is to simply import the obj in Blender, select it, apply the texture and export it:

[image: blender texture material display]

(This would also be a good opportunity to rotate/scale models so when they're loaded in Processing, no additional transforms are required and they all can live an in easy to understand coordinate system)

The contents of the exported files I've used are:

- [cirno_lowWithMTL.mtl](https://lifesine.eu/so/cirno_lowWithMTL.mtl)
- [cirno_lowWithMTL.obj](https://lifesine.eu/so/cirno_lowWithMTL.obj)
- [cirno_lowWithMTLDecimated.mtl](https://lifesine.eu/so/cirno_lowWithMTLDecimated.mtl)
- [cirno_lowWithMTLDecimated.obj](https://lifesine.eu/so/cirno_lowWithMTLDecimated.obj)

They load/display (with textures) at 60fps (due to the .mtl files)
[image: loaded obj with .mtl files rendered at 60fps in Processing]

The recommended optimisation steps (other than using .obj with .mtl files and loading once and re-using mulitple times) are:

- avoid extending fixed length arrays (e.g. `kryptonit = (Kryptonit[]) append(kryptonit, new Kryptonit(int(random(50, width-150)), int(random(-300, 0))));`). [`ArrayLists`](https://processing.org/reference/ArrayList.html) are better suited for resizing. In this case in particular a fixed length array is great, as long as it's objects are pre-allocated once, then the positions / states of the objects are updated (e.g. outside of screen objects are marked for re-use and hidden and instead of new objects, existing objects have positions visiblity/reset): in other words [Object Pooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern))
- if meshes are displayed from a single point of view with only rotation on Z axis and position affecting them, they could be images (sprites) instead. (e.g. exporting a static image with alpha channel from Blender at the right scale (or using [PGraphics](https://processing.org/reference/PGraphics.html) to do this at runtime))
- once meshes are loaded, instead of using transformations on them in draw() (e.g. `symbol.rotateX(value)`, which will affect every single vertex in the `PShape`, use `pushMatrix()/popMatrix()` call with `shape()` so simply render the same geometry with different tranformations.

For reference this is the full program with minimal tweaks around loading/using .obj files efficiently (with the old approach commented out and few notes around those regions):

```java
import com.dhchoi.CountdownTimer;
import com.dhchoi.CountdownTimerService;
import controlP5.*;

int zeit;
int punkte;
int leben;
int schwierigkeit = 20;
int zustand = 1;
int boost = 0;
int highscore = 0;
int minuten = 0;

int changeLevel = 0;
boolean paused = true;
boolean gameOver;
JSONArray saves = new JSONArray();
        
PFont gameOverFont;
PFont gameOverFontSmall;

CountdownTimer timer1 = CountdownTimerService.getNewCountdownTimer(this).configure(1000, 60000);
CountdownTimer kryptonitAnimationTimer1 = CountdownTimerService.getNewCountdownTimer(this).configure(10, 250);

boolean[] keysPressed = new boolean[65536];
ControlP5 cp5;

Star[] stars;
Kryptonit[] kryptonit;
Raumschiff raumschiff;

Player[] players;

String textValue = "";

PImage cirnoTexture;
PImage rockTexture;

PShape cirno;
PShape rock;

void loadMeshes(){
  rock = loadShape("rockWithMTL.obj");
  rock.scale(0.2);
  
  cirno = loadShape("cirno_lowWithMTL.obj");
  cirno.rotateY(HALF_PI);
  cirno.rotateZ(HALF_PI * -1);
  cirno.scale(5);
}

void settings()
{
    //size(800, 400, P3D);
    fullScreen(P3D);
    smooth(8);
    System.setProperty("jogl.disable.openglcore", "true");
}

void setup() {
  surface.setResizable(true);
  
  //println("loading textures");
  //cirnoTexture = loadImage("cirno_low_u1_v1.jpeg");
  //rockTexture = loadImage("rockTexture.png");
  //println("finished loading textures: " + cirnoTexture);
  loadMeshes();
  
    stars = new Star[0];
    kryptonit = new Kryptonit[0];
    raumschiff = new Raumschiff(width/2, height/4*3, cirno);
    leben = 5;
    gameOverFont = createFont("Arial", 36, true);
    gameOverFontSmall = createFont("Arial", 16, true);
    for (int i = 0; i < schwierigkeit; i++) {
        stars = (Star[]) append(stars, new Star(int(random(50, width-150)), int(random(50, height-100)), int(random(5, 15)), rock));
    }

    players = new Player[0];

    cp5 = new ControlP5(this);

    cp5.addTextfield("Name")
        .setPosition(width/2-100, height/3*2-20)
        .setSize(200, 40)
        .setFont(gameOverFontSmall)
        .setFocus(false)
        .setColor(color(255))
        .setAutoClear(false)
        .setText("Name")
        .setLabel("")
        .hide()
        .lock()
        ;

  
  
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  lights();
    switch (zustand) {
        case 0:
        break;
        case 1:
      fill(255);
            text("Zeit:\t" + minuten + ":" + zeit, width-100, 50);
            text("Punkte:\t" + punkte, width-100 , 100);
            text("Leben:\t" + leben, width-100, 150);
            text("Highscore:\t" + highscore, width-100, 200);
            text("schwierigkeit:\t" + schwierigkeit, width-100, 250);
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
                    text(players[i].getName() + "   " + players[i].getScore(), width-100, 300+15*i);
                }
                
        for (int i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
          stars[i].zeichnen();
          stars[i].drehen(random(0, 0.05), random(0, 0.05), random(0, 0.05));
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < kryptonit.length; i++) {
                    kryptonit[i].zeichnen();
                }
                if (kryptonitAnimationTimer1.getTimeLeftUntilFinish() != .0f) {
                    raumschiff.zeichnen(color(350-kryptonitAnimationTimer1.getTimeLeftUntilFinish(), 100, 100));
                } else {
                    raumschiff.zeichnen(color(100, 100, 100));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            noFill();
            stroke(100);
            rect(50, 50, width-200, height-150);
            fill(0);
            noStroke();
            rect(0, 0, width-150, 48);
            if (gameOver) {
                pushMatrix();
                fill(255);
                textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
                textFont(gameOverFont, 36);
                textSize(34);
                text("GAME OVER!", width/2, height/2);
                textFont(gameOverFontSmall, 16);
                textSize(16);
                text("Press ENTER to resume", width/2, height/2+30);
                cp5.get(Textfield.class, "Name").unlock();
                cp5.get(Textfield.class, "Name").show();
                popMatrix();
            }
            else if (paused) {
                pushMatrix();
                fill(255);
                textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
                textFont(gameOverFont, 36);
                textSize(34);
                text("PAUSED!", width/2, height/2);
                textFont(gameOverFontSmall, 16);
                textSize(16);
                text("PRESS ANY KEY TO RESUME", width/2, height/2+30);
                popMatrix();
            }
        break;
        default :
            background(0);
        break;  
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
        if (stars[i].isVisible && sqrt((stars[i].posX - raumschiff.posX) * (stars[i].posX - raumschiff.posX) + (stars[i].posY - raumschiff.posY) * (stars[i].posY - raumschiff.posY) ) < 25){
            stars[i].isVisible = false;
            punkte+=stars[i].speed;
            if (changeLevel > 0) {
                changeLevel--;
            }
        }
    }
    if (punkte > highscore) {
        highscore = punkte;
    }
    if (kryptonit.length < schwierigkeit / 5) {
        //kryptonit = (Kryptonit[]) append(kryptonit, new Kryptonit(int(random(50, width-150)), int(random(-300, 0))));
    }
    if (stars.length < schwierigkeit) {
        stars = (Star[]) append(stars, new Star(int(random(50, width-150)), int(random(-300, 0)), int(random(5, 15)), rock));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < kryptonit.length; i++) {
        if (kryptonit[i].isVisible && sqrt((kryptonit[i].posX - raumschiff.posX) * (kryptonit[i].posX - raumschiff.posX) + (kryptonit[i].posY - raumschiff.posY) * (kryptonit[i].posY - raumschiff.posY) ) < 25){
            kryptonit[i].isVisible = false;
            leben-=1;
            kryptonitAnimationTimer1.start();
        }
    }
    if (leben < 1){
        gameOver = true;
    }

    if (punkte % 500 <= 20 && punkte % 500 >= 0 && changeLevel == 0 && zustand == 1) {
        schwierigkeit+=5;
        changeLevel = 5;
    }
    if (punkte % 500 > 20) {
        changeLevel = 0;
    }



    if (!paused) {
        try {
            if (!gameOver) {
                for (int i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
                    stars[i].bewegen(schwierigkeit/stars[i].speed+boost);
                    if (stars[i].posY > height-100){
                        stars[i] = null;
                        stars[i] = new Star(int(random(58, width-202)), int(random(-300, 0)), int(random(5, 15)), rock);
                    }
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < kryptonit.length; i++){
                    kryptonit[i].bewegen(schwierigkeit/10+boost);
                    if (kryptonit[i].posY > height-100){
                        kryptonit[i] = null;
                        kryptonit[i] = new Kryptonit(int(random(58, width-202)), int(random(-300, 0)));
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    if (keysPressed[56]){
        boost = 5;
    }
    else {
        boost = 0;
    }
    if (keysPressed[52] && !gameOver && !paused){
        try {
            raumschiff.bewegen(-7);
            if (keysPressed[32]) {
                raumschiff.bewegen(-10);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
    if (keysPressed[54] && !gameOver && !paused){
        try {
            raumschiff.bewegen(7);
            if (keysPressed[32]) {
                raumschiff.bewegen(10);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
  surface.setTitle((int)frameRate+"fps");
}


void keyPressed() {
    if (gameOver && key == ENTER) {
        players = (Player[]) append(players, new Player(cp5.get(Textfield.class, "Name").getText(), punkte));
        cp5.get(Textfield.class, "Name").lock();
        cp5.get(Textfield.class, "Name").hide();
        for (int i = 0; i < saves.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject playerJSONObject = new JSONObject();
            playerJSONObject.setInt("id", i);
            playerJSONObject.setString(cp5.get("Name", cp5.get(Textfield.class, "Name").getText()).toString(), "");
            playerJSONObject.setInt("score", punkte);
        }
        saveJSONArray(saves, "data/highscores.json");

        schwierigkeit = 20;
        paused = true;
        gameOver = false;
        leben = 5;
        punkte = 0;
        timer1.reset(CountdownTimer.StopBehavior.STOP_IMMEDIATELY);
        timer1.start();
        zeit = 0;
        stars = null;
        stars = new Star[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < schwierigkeit; i++) {
            stars = (Star[]) append(stars, new Star(int(random(50, width-150)), int(random(50, height-100)), int(random(5, 15)), rock));
        }
        kryptonit = null;
        kryptonit = new Kryptonit[0];
    }
    keysPressed[key] = true;
}

void keyReleased() {
    keysPressed[key] = false;
}

void keyTyped() {
    if (key == 'p' || key == 'P') {
        if (!gameOver) {
            paused = !paused;
            if (paused) {
                timer1.stop(CountdownTimer.StopBehavior.STOP_IMMEDIATELY);
            }
            else {
                timer1.start();
            }
        }
    }
    if (paused && !gameOver && key != 'p' && key != 'P') {
        paused = false;
        timer1.start();
    }
}

void onTickEvent(CountdownTimer t, long timeLeftUntilFinish) {
    if (t == timer1) {
        zeit++;
    }
}

void onFinishEvent(CountdownTimer t) {
    if (t == timer1) {
        timer1.reset(CountdownTimer.StopBehavior.STOP_AFTER_INTERVAL);
        timer1.start();
        zeit = 0;
        minuten++;
    }
}
abstract class Flugobjekt {
    public int posX;
    public int posY;
    public int rot;
    public int speed;
    boolean isVisible = true;

    PShape symbol;

    abstract void bewegen (int amount);
}

abstract class UFO extends Flugobjekt {

}

public class Star extends UFO {
  
  float rotationX, rotationY, rotationZ; 
  
    public Star (int x, int y, int spd, PShape symbol) {
        posX = x;
        posY = y;
        rot = int(random(0, 360));
        speed = spd;  
    // use a reference to the preloaded PShape (instead of loading a the .obj again for each instance)
    this.symbol = symbol;
    //symbol = loadShape("rockWithMTL.obj");
    //symbol.setTexture(rockTexture);
    //symbol.scale(0.2);
    /*
        fill(255);
        stroke(255);
        strokeWeight(2);
        symbol = createShape();
        symbol.beginShape();
        symbol.vertex(0, -5);
        symbol.vertex(1.4, -2);
        symbol.vertex(4.7, -1.5);
        symbol.vertex(2.3, 0.7);
        symbol.vertex(2.9, 4.0);
        symbol.vertex(0, 2.5);
        symbol.vertex(-2.9, 4);
        symbol.vertex(-2.3, 0.7);
        symbol.vertex(-4.7, -1.5);
        symbol.vertex(-1.4, -2);
        symbol.endShape(CLOSE);
    /*/
    }

    public void zeichnen (){ 
    // skip if PShape (or it's texture) isn't loaded yet)
    if(symbol == null){
      return;
    }
    if (isVisible) {
            pushMatrix();
            translate(posX, posY);
            //rotate(rot);
      rotateX(rotationX);
      rotateY(rotationY);
      rotateZ(rotationZ);
      //scale(0.2);
            shape(symbol);
            popMatrix();
        }
    }

    public void bewegen (int amount) {
        posY = posY + amount;
    }

  public void drehen (float xAmount, float yAmount, float zAmount) {
   rotationX += xAmount;
   rotationY += yAmount;
   rotationZ += zAmount;
   // symbol.rotateX means all vertices inside the shape will be updated
   // use rotateX() then shape() to simply render the same underlying PShape vertex data without updating it all the time
    //symbol.rotateX(xAmount);
    //symbol.rotateY(yAmount);
    //symbol.rotateZ(zAmount);
  }
}

public class Kryptonit extends UFO {
    public Kryptonit (int x, int y) {
        posX = x;
        posY = y;
        rot = int(random(0, 360));
        fill(0);
        stroke(255, 0, 0);
        strokeWeight(2);
        symbol = createShape();
        symbol.beginShape();
        symbol.vertex(0, -5);
        symbol.vertex(1.4, -2);
        symbol.vertex(4.7, -1.5);
        symbol.vertex(2.3, 0.7);
        symbol.vertex(2.9, 4.0);
        symbol.vertex(0, 2.5);
        symbol.vertex(-2.9, 4);
        symbol.vertex(-2.3, 0.7);
        symbol.vertex(-4.7, -1.5);
        symbol.vertex(-1.4, -2);
        symbol.endShape(CLOSE);
    }

    public void zeichnen (){ 
        if (isVisible) {
            pushMatrix();
            translate(posX, posY);
            rotate(rot);
            shape(symbol);
            popMatrix();
        }
    }

    public void bewegen (int amount) {
        posY = posY + amount;
    }
}

public class Raumschiff extends Flugobjekt {
    public Raumschiff (int x, int y, PShape symbol) {
        posX = x;
        posY = y;
        fill(100);
        noStroke();
    this.symbol = symbol;
        //symbol = loadShape("cirno_lowWithMTL.obj");//createShape(ELLIPSE, 0, 0, 50, 50);
    //symbol.setTexture(cirnoTexture);
    //symbol.rotateY(HALF_PI);
    //symbol.rotateZ(HALF_PI * -1);
    ////symbol.rotateX(0.5);
    //symbol.scale(5);
        /*          (Raumschiff)
    symbol = createShape();
    symbol.beginShape();
        symbol.vertex(25, 0);
        symbol.vertex(30, 5);
        symbol.vertex(30, 5);
        symbol.vertex(32, 12);
        symbol.vertex(28, 20);
        symbol.vertex(31, 28);
        symbol.vertex(27, 25);
        symbol.vertex(25, 29);
        symbol.vertex(23, 25);
        symbol.vertex(19, 28);
        symbol.vertex(22, 20);
        symbol.vertex(18, 12);
        symbol.vertex(20, 5);
        symbol.endShape(CLOSE);
        //*/
    }

    public void zeichnen (color farbe){ 
        if (isVisible) {
            pushMatrix();
            symbol.setFill(farbe);
            translate(posX, posY);
            rotate(rot);
            shape(symbol);
            popMatrix();
        }
    }

    public void bewegen (int amount) {
        posX+=amount;
        if (posX < 50) posX = 50;
        if (posX > width-150) posX = width-150;
    }
}
public class Player {

    private String name;
    private int score;

    public Player (String n, int s) {
        name = n;
        score = s;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
}
```

Here's an example of pre-allocating a number of objects to be reused (a-la object pooling), instead of constant reinstantiation (which has it's costs):

```java
PShape rock;
int numRocks = 25;
Rock[] rocks = new Rock[numRocks];

float halfWidth;
float halfHeight;

void setup(){
  size(900, 900, P3D);
  rock = loadShape("rockWithMTL.obj");
  // ideally the mesh would already been scaled down to avoid this
  rock.scale(0.2);
  
  halfWidth  = width * 0.5;
  halfHeight = height * 0.5;
  
  for(int i = 0 ; i < numRocks; i++){
    rocks[i] = new Rock(rock, random(-halfWidth, halfWidth), random(-halfHeight, halfHeight));
  }
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  lights();
  translate(width * 0.5, height * 0.5, 0);
  
  for(int i = 0 ; i < numRocks; i++){
    rocks[i].draw();
  }
  
  surface.setTitle((int)frameRate + "fps");
}

class Rock{
  
  PShape mesh;
  PVector position = new PVector();
  PVector velocity = new PVector();
  
  PVector rotationAxis = new PVector();
  float rotationAngle = 0;
  
  Rock(PShape mesh, float x, float y){
    this.mesh = mesh;
    position.x = x;
    position.y = y;
    velocity.y = random(1, 10);
    // pick a random rotation axis
    rotationAxis.set(random(1), random(1), random(1));
  }
  
  void draw(){
    // update
    // increment position
    position.add(velocity);
    // increment rotation
    rotationAngle += 0.1;
    // object pool behaviour: reset if off screen (no need to re-allocate a new instance)
    if(position.y > halfHeight + 100){
      position.x = random(-halfWidth, halfWidth);
      position.y = -halfHeight - 100;
    }
    // draw
    pushMatrix();
    translate(position.x, position.y, position.z);
    rotate(rotationAngle, rotationAxis.x, rotationAxis.y, rotationAxis.z);
    shape(mesh);
    popMatrix();
  }
  
}
```

Also, here's a super basic demo on encapsulating states. It's a bit hacky because each state know of the other, but shows each could behave as it's own "sketch" that can live in it's own tab and only override it's specific behaviour:

```java
StartScreen start;
GameScreen game;
HighScoreScreen highScore;
StateScreen currentScreen;

void setup(){
  size(300, 300);
  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  textSize(18);
  
  start = new StartScreen();
  game = new GameScreen();
  highScore = new HighScoreScreen();
  
  currentScreen = start;
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  currentScreen.draw();
}

void keyPressed(){
  currentScreen.keyPressed();
}


class StateScreen {
  StateScreen(){
    setup();
  }
  void setup(){   println(this,"setup()"); }
  void draw(){}
  void keyPressed(){}
}

class StartScreen extends StateScreen{
  void draw(){
    fill(sin(frameCount * 0.1) * 127);
    text("push any key to\nstart", width * 0.5, height * 0.5);
  }
  void keyPressed(){
    currentScreen = game;
  }
} 
class GameScreen extends StateScreen{
  void draw(){
    fill(0, sin(frameCount * 0.1) * 127, 0);
    text("push SPACE key to go to\nhigh score screen", width * 0.5, height * 0.5);
  }
  void keyPressed(){
    currentScreen = highScore;
  }
}
class HighScoreScreen extends StateScreen{
  void draw(){
    fill(random(255), random(255), random(255));
    text("push SPACE key to go to\nstart screen", width * 0.5, height * 0.5);
  }
  void keyPressed(){
    currentScreen = start;
  }
}
```